# How to Identify the most accessed column in Your table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, etl

This is my first time so please bear with me. ;)

I work in a department where we have to tune up the stored procedures and/or select statements to speed up the searches of reports .

I need help to query a specific table at a time and get a 'hit' results on of each column of that table.

That way I can add indexes to columns that are searched the most.

A bunch of the tables that I am working with have been horribly built and now they have over a million rows to 5 mill rows with no primary keys or indexes (on most).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

P.S. I had a query like it from my last company I worked for and used it few times - I know it exists and is very helpful. Thanks to all.

Comment: I see you've tagged `sql-server`.  Have you tried displaying your query's Execution Plan in SQL Server Management Studio??

Comment: Are you using mySQL or Microsoft's SQL Server. The answers will differ for each DB. And, if using mySQL, which engine(s) do you need this info for?

Comment: If you're on SQL Server Enterprise, you may have a look SQL Server Audit - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280404.aspx